# When many list are added, the page is obscured. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, parcel

Thank you! Now, It works very well :D

---

I have a CSS problem.
I use `overflow: auto`. But, when many list are added, the page is obscured. How can I fix it?
I used parcel-bundler. Here is my app. [Link](https://imki123.github.io/todo_vanilla/)
Help me.
[image]

Comment: its looking fine in my browser

Comment: @Aahad, add item such as the height of items > viewport height

Comment: can you explain??

Comment: It works fine for me as well.  What do you actually mean by "obscured"?  Everything seems to be displayed as intended - each item expands with a vertical scrollbar and all items are displayed.  Isn't that what is supposed to happen?

Comment: @ATD At page of top, the title is hidden

Comment: That's not really "obscured".  If you want to keep the title at the top of the page, you need to set its css to include `position:sticky;' and `top:0px;`  That way, it will always be at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common when using flexbox to center a box vertically. You can fix it by adding `margin: auto` to `.todo`

```
.todo {
    background: #fff;
    min-width: 500px;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove you `overflow:auto;` from `wrapper` and set it to `todo` with `max-height: 100%;`

(wait I saw a problem created on your button then because it is loosing its position please use @AdamAzad answer)